# Angular2 Firebase File-Upload

Tags: angular, file-upload, firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire2

Is it possible to use the ng2-file-upload (https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload) to upload files to firebase? I tried it with setting the uploadUrl to

```
this.uploaderUrl = firebase.storage().ref();
this.uploaderUrl.child('images').child(this.image.title);
```

and

```
public uploader: FileUploader = new FileUploader({
   url: this.uploaderUrl,
   authToken: this.authService.authState.uid
});
```

But that didn´t work as expected.

Comment: I am also wondering how I can do this.

Comment: You can user AngularFireDatabase.storage() to upload files.